# Trouble to access attributes by using glVertexArrayAttribFormat / glVertexArrayVertexBuffer

Tags: c++, opengl

I have this code :

```
Upp::Vector<float> verticesTriangle{
     1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
     0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,
};

glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
glBindVertexArray(VAO);

//Setting up the VAO Attribute format
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0); //Will be colors (R G B in float)
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3); //Will be texture coordinates
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5); //Normals
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8); //Will be my position 

glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 0);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 1);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 2);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 3);

//Generating a VBO
glGenBuffers(1, &VBOCarre);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOCarre);
glBufferStorage(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(float) * verticesTriangle.GetCount(), verticesTriangle, GL_MAP_READ_BIT  | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);

//Binding the VBO to be read by VAO
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(VAO, 0, VBOCarre, 0 * sizeof(float), 11 * sizeof(float));
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(VAO, 1, VBOCarre, 3 * sizeof(float), 11 * sizeof(float));
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(VAO, 2, VBOCarre, 5 * sizeof(float), 11 * sizeof(float));
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(VAO, 3, VBOCarre, 8 * sizeof(float), 11 * sizeof(float));
//Bind VAO
glBindVertexArray(VAO);
```

I have no problem retrieving the first attribute in my shader however, when I trying to retrieve others, It dont work. To test it, I have setup an float array and a simple shader program and I try to retrieve my position to draw a triangle.
Here is how my datas are ordered :

[image: how my datas are ordered]

Here is my vertex shader :

```
#version 400 
layout (location = 0) in vec3 colors;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 textCoords;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 normals;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 positions;

out vec3 fs_colors;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(positions.x, positions.y, positions.z, 1.0);
//  gl_Position = vec4(colors.x, colors.y, colors.z, 1.0); //This line work, proofing my
//  first attribute is sended well to my shader
    fs_colors = colors;
}
```

**The problem is, except the first attribute, all others seems to not be sent to the shader. What am I missing ?!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're putting stuff in the wrong place.

> ```
> glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3); //Will be texture coordinates
> ```

The "3" here is being passed as a *byte offset* from the start of a vertex in the array to the particular data for that vertex in the attribute. Obviously, your texture coordinate is not 3 bytes from the start of your vertex; it's `3 * sizeof(float)` bytes from the start of the vertex.

Similarly:

> ```
> glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(VAO, 1, VBOCarre, 3 * sizeof(float), 11 * sizeof(float));
> ```

This makes no sense either. You're only using a single buffer, and all four attributes read from the same binding. So you should only bind a single buffer.

The offset ought to be 0, because that's where a vertex in the buffer starts. And the stride should be what you wrote.

You also never directly set the association between the attributes and the binding index with `glVertexArrayAttribBinding`. You probably got things to work by relying on the default, but you shouldn't be using the default here.

The correct code would be:

```
//Generating a VBO
glCreateBuffers(1, &VBOCarre);
//No need to call glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBOCarre);, since we're doing DSA.

glNamedBufferStorage(VBOCarre, sizeof(float) * verticesTriangle.GetCount(), verticesTriangle, GL_MAP_READ_BIT  | GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT);


glCreateVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
//No need to glBindVertexArray(VAO);, since we're using DSA.

//Setting up the VAO Attribute format
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0); //Will be colors (R G B in float)
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 1);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float)); //Will be texture coordinates
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 2);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 2, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float)); //Normals
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(VAO, 3);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(VAO, 3, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float)); //Will be my position 

//One buffer, one binding.
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(VAO, 0, VBOCarre, 0, 11 * sizeof(float));

//Make all attributes read from the same buffer.
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(VAO, 0, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(VAO, 1, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(VAO, 2, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(VAO, 3, 0);

//We can glBindVertexArray(VAO); when we're about to use it, not just because we finished setting it up.
```